# How to open a project in Intellij from taskbar?

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently updated the Intellij-idea from 13.1 to 13.1.7.

When I try to open recently closed projects by right-click the Intellij icon in taskbar - getting this error in Event log

> Unauthorized Operation: The command line launcher is outdated. Please refresh it (via Tools | Create Command-line Launcher)

It used to work fine with 13.1.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the instructions given in the message that you posted as part of your question?

Comment: @yole I couldn't find the Command-Line Launcher option under Tools